# como deixar todos itens de uma div na horizontal

Tags: html, css

html

```
<div id="containerprodutos" class="containerprodutos">
                <div id="containerprodutosfilha" class="containerprodutosfilha">
            <h3 class="text-center align-middle"><img class="imgcar" src="images/<?= $mostrar['skin_img']?>"></h3>
                <h3 class="text-center align-middle"><strong><p class="nomecar"><?= $produtos; ?></p></strong></h3>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

como está :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na div `class="containerprodutosfilha` coloca `display:flex`

```css
.containerprodutosfilha {
    display:flex
}
```

```html
<div id="containerprodutos" class="containerprodutos">
    <div id="containerprodutosfilha" class="containerprodutosfilha" >
        <h3 class="text-center align-middle"><img class="imgcar" src="https://placecage.com/100/100"> </h3>
        <h3 class="text-center align-middle"><strong><p class="nomecar"><?= $produtos; ?> texto </p></strong></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```